# New Firebase Initialize Crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

```
FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
```

When i call this the app crashes the error log says FirebaseApp doesn't exist.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

So i tried to initialised FireBase Myself. so, new code looks like

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, FirebaseOptions.fromResource(this));
FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
```

The new issue is quite the opposite. Check the crash Log it says that FirebaseApp already exists

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!
     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
```

Did my Firebase App initialised/ should i initialise it ?? Because in both cases my app crashes and even crash reports are not working. Here is the crash report error

```
E/FirebaseCrashSenderServiceImpl: Error sending crash report
    ait: Server did not receive report: Origin Error message: Mobile Crash and Performance Reporting API has not been used in project project-546786591250077938 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mobilecrashreporting.googleapis.com/overview?project=project-XXXXXXXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
    at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashSenderServiceImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:299)
    at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashSenderServiceImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:146)
    at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashSenderServiceImpl.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:108)
    at aid.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:69)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
    at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzf$zza$zza.zzI(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashSenderService.onHandleIntent(Unknown Source)
```

My build.gradle

```
ext {
    firebaseVersion = "9.0.0"
}
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${firebaseVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:${firebaseVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:${firebaseVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:${firebaseVersion}"
}
```

Comment: Possibly a stupid question but did you add the app in the firebase dashboard?

Comment: @IvanWooll ofcourse i did. Else how can i get the Json from firebase

Comment: Remove the firebase-core dependency and try again

Comment: @ThanosF firebase core is for analytics

Comment: @AshokVarma Then replace it with `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0'` You don't need the core really.

Comment: @ThanosF please check the documentation. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries) there is no compile time dependency for analytics separately. core includes the analytics.

Comment: @AshokVarma Check this sample on github. Hope it helps https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/analytics/app/build.gradle

Comment: @ThanosF Thankyou. i changed it still i have same issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you calling `FirebaseRemoteConfig` in an `Application` subclass? You may be hitting the issue where the `background_crash` also instantiates an app subclass, and therefore executes your code on a process where the FirebaseApp isn't set up. If you look at the full stack trace you should be able to see what process it occurred on near the top.

FirebaseApp is normally configured by a `ContentProvider` automatically merged in to your manifest by the Firebase SDK. Initializing Firebase Remote Config causes it to try and read from its local cache, which involves getting the app ID value from `FirebaseApp`. If you want to guard against uninitialized errors, then you can either move your code to an `Activity`, or check whether you have a `FirebaseApp` instance before calling the `RemoteConfig` code in your `Application` subclass:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
    FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();

  }
}
```

If its not that, check you aren't getting any errors from the `google-services` plugin at build time.

Comment: Where can I learn more about `background_crash`?  It appears in an [ANR I am seeing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357974/after-upgrading-to-google-play-services-9-0-0-app-hangs-in-dynamitemodulesc) after upgrading to Google Play Services 9.0.0.

Comment: Yes i am calling that from Application Subclass. Because i need some remoteConfig values in my application initialisation. Is there any other way to do this? and also what if Firebase Initialization didn't happened even in the first activity ??

Comment: The initialisation will happen fine for the app subclass - the issue is it only happens for the main process and not the background_crash process. The check I suggested effectively means you init code only runs on the main process, not the background one.

Comment: @IanBarber the solution worked. But is there anyother way to do this.