# App stops responding after resuming from background sometimes. Could Firebase be to blame?

Tags: android, firebase, google-tag-manager

App stops responding every few resumes. This only happens on the release build, not the debug build. It happens on any activity, and there doesn't seem to be any pattern to it at all. I finally caught the below ANR in logcat. I'm not very familiar with Google Tag Manager, but I'm not explicitly using it in my app, but I was thinking maybe Firebase does use it for analytics. If that is the case, is there any way to turn analytics off? Any other suggestions?

**ANR**

```
ANR in com.levipayne.liferpg, time=9836523
                                                  PID: 11504
                                                  Reason: executing service com.levipayne.liferpg/com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerService
                                                  Load: 11.71 / 11.74 / 11.77
                                                  CPU usage from 129888ms to 0ms ago:
                                                    3.9% 1071/system_server: 2.4% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 10368 minor 11 major
                                                    2% 2853/mpdecision: 0.2% user + 1.7% kernel
                                                    1.5% 1496/com.android.systemui: 1.1% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 414 minor 11 major
                                                    1.2% 1966/com.android.phone: 1% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 1141 minor 1 major
                                                    0.8% 9190/kworker/0:3: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
                                                    0.6% 374/rild: 0.5% user + 0% kernel / faults: 125 minor
                                                    0.6% 354/logd: 0.2% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                    0.5% 20278/adbd: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
                                                    0.5% 385/tpd_daemon: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
                                                    0.4% 375/surfaceflinger: 0.1% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                    0.4% 14939/logcat: 0.1% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                    0.2% 251/ueventd: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                    0.2% 12737/com.amazon.kindle: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 989 minor 2 major
                                                    0.2% 2648/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 617 minor
                                                    0.2% 4001/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 7/kworker/u:0H: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 373/servicemanager: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                    0.2% 8242/kworker/u:1: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 9642/kworker/u:5: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 247/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 12625/com.amazon.mShop.android: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3299 minor
                                                    0.2% 627/logcat: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                    0.2% 32749/kworker/0:2H: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 619/htc_ebdlogd: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 30667/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.1% 9334/kworker/u:4: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                    0.1% 1991/android.process.acore: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 827 minor
                                                    0.1% 2636/com.android.bluetooth: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1322 minor 10 major
                                                    0.1% 1477/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0.1% 2672/irq/33-cpubw_hw: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                    0.1% 30448/com.amazon.mp3: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
                                                    0% 470/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8293 minor
                                                    0% 1468/MC_Thread: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 2825/pnpmgr: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 11777/com.ra3al.clock: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1432 minor
                                                    0% 2619/com.vcast.mediamanager: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
                                                    0% 12427/com.htc.sense.mms: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1395 minor 9 major
                                                    0% 1470/RX_Thread: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 5767/com.htc.sense.hsp: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1176 minor
                                                    0% 11710/com.estrongs.android.pop: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
                                                    0% 6662/com.google.android.gms: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 41 minor
                                                    0% 4150/com.asurion.android.verizon.vms: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
                                                    0% 4537/com.verizon.messaging.vzmsgs: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 27 minor
                                                    0% 370/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 382/qmuxd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 19 minor
                                                    0% 1469/TX_Thread: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 1//init: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 13 minor
                                                    0% 275/flush-179:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 521/mdss_fb0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 626/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 2099/com.qualcomm.qti.tetherservice: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 5407/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 13 minor
                                                    0% 6415/com.telecomsys.directedsms.android.SCG: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 10832/com.android.settings: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
                                                    0% 20224/com.nero.android.htc.sync: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 8/migration/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 34/kworker/u:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 267/jbd2/mmcblk0p39: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 369/healthd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 458/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 49 minor
                                                    0% 1790/com.google.android.wearable.app: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 554 minor
                                                    0% 2/kthreadd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 189/dbs_sync/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 191/dbs_sync/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 193/dbs_sync/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 259/jbd2/mmcblk0p49: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 355/vold: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 383/netmgrd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0% 471/t
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and solved it by replacing the dependency `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0` with the ones I actually used as described in the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37379662/4134617

My build.gradle ended up like this.

```
    dependencies {
      compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
      compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.0.0"
      compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0"
      compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0"
      compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: I have save issue, but i need `com.google.android.gms.location` and can't remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0`

Comment: It works also for Google Analytics 'compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'

Comment: @Geka you can still include com.google.android.gms:play-location:9.0.0 without including the core lib

Comment: Thanks! Changed it to 9.0.2 - solved my issues (After 3 days of debugging...)