# How to spot app freeze causes when app is returning from pause state?

Tags: android

My App is facing a really weird behavior:

1. App is started normally;
2. I leave the app for another one or back to the phone's home screen;
3. When I try to go back to the previous app instance, it hangs until I get the "App is not responding, force it to close?";

I know it sounds like some memory leak or loop stuck problem, but this behavior is complety random (sometimes I perform the steps above twice and I get the problem, other times I do it like ten times until I get the error). No Exception is thrown in the logcat. In the Monitor, alocated memory never explodes and it keeps below the free memory. I've used the memory analizer and nothing weird is shown in report.

I've noticed already that when I use loader spinners in my Activity, the number of times needed performing the steps above in order for the App to crash decreases - sometimes doing them once makes the app crash.

Does anyone have a suggestion of what can I do in order to figure out what might be causing this problem?

Thank you.

## EDIT

This behavior can happen in any of the App's activities, Logcat and code can be foundbelow:

All my activities are descendant of this template:

```
public abstract class ActivityTemplate extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Boolean isRunning = Boolean.TRUE;

    private ToolbarManager mToolbarManager;
    private ActivitySetup mSetup;

    public abstract ActivitySetup setUpActivity();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mToolbarManager = new ToolbarManager();
        mSetup = setUpActivity();
        setContentView(mSetup.getContentView());
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        prepareToolbar();
        registerForEvents();
        this.startResources();
    }

    private void prepareToolbar() {
        if (mSetup.getHasToolbar()) {
            mToolbarManager.initToolbar(this, mSetup.getTitle(), R.id.toolbar, R.color.textPrimary);
            if (mSetup.getDefaultReturnBehavior()) {
                mToolbarManager.setNavigationReturnBehavior();
            }
            mToolbarManager.prepareNavigationBehavior(mSetup.getNavigationIcon(), mSetup.getOnNavigationItemClicked());
        }
    }

    public void startResources() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.unregisterForEvents();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.isRunning = Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.isRunning = Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void registerForEvents() {
        Map<EventCatalog, TaskExecutor> executors = this.setEventHandlers();
        if (null != executors && executors.size() > 0) {
            for (EventCatalog event : executors.keySet()) {
                NotificationCenter.RegistrationCenter.registerForEvent(event, executors.get(event));
            }
        }
    }

    public void unregisterForEvents() {
        Map<EventCatalog, TaskExecutor> executors = this.setEventHandlers();
        if (null != executors && executors.size() > 0) {
            for (EventCatalog key : executors.keySet()) {
                NotificationCenter.RegistrationCenter.unregisterForEvent(key, executors.get(key));
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return this.isRunning;
    }

    public Toolbar getToolbar() {
        return mToolbarManager.getToolbar();
    }

    public Map<EventCatalog, TaskExecutor> setEventHandlers() {
        return null;
    }
}



06-13 10:39:11.258 25215-25271/br.com.gogame I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.3_RB1__release_AU (I3193f6e94a)
                                                               OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.28.00.02
                                                               Build Date: 10/09/15 Fri
                                                               Local Branch: mybranch15039904
                                                               Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.3_rb1.2
                                                               Local Patches: NONE
                                                               Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
    06-13 10:39:11.274 25215-25271/br.com.gogame I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    06-13 10:39:11.315 25215-25215/br.com.gogame E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    06-13 10:39:11.315 25215-25215/br.com.gogame E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    06-13 10:39:11.601 25215-25215/br.com.gogame E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    06-13 10:39:11.601 25215-25215/br.com.gogame E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    06-13 10:39:11.640 25215-25215/br.com.gogame E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    06-13 10:39:11.640 25215-25215/br.com.gogame E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    06-13 10:39:20.864 25215-25241/br.com.gogame E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.com.gogame-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/br.com.gogame-1/lib/arm, /data/app/br.com.gogame-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    06-13 10:39:25.202 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.crash.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.com.gogame-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/br.com.gogame-1/lib/arm, /data/app/br.com.gogame-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    06-13 10:39:25.239 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Reading stored module config
    06-13 10:39:25.299 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:2
    06-13 10:39:25.299 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.crash, version >= 2
    06-13 10:39:25.312 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/n/armeabi-v7a
    06-13 10:39:25.312 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/n/armeabi
    06-13 10:39:25.313 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is armeabi-v7a
    06-13 10:39:25.314 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
    06-13 10:39:25.334 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash I/FirebaseCrashReceiverServiceImpl: FirebaseCrashReceiverServiceImpl created by ClassLoader com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.DelegateLastPathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_xxhdpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/n/armeabi-v7a, /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/n/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]
    06-13 10:39:25.340 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash D/FirebaseCrashReceiverServiceImpl: onCreate
    06-13 10:39:25.345 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:1
    06-13 10:39:25.345 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.flags, version >= 1
    06-13 10:39:25.379 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash I/FirebaseCrashSenderServiceImpl: FirebaseCrashSenderServiceImpl created by ClassLoader com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.DelegateLastPathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_xxhdpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/n/armeabi-v7a, /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/n/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]
    06-13 10:39:25.379 25575-25575/br.com.gogame:background_crash D/FirebaseCrashSenderServiceImpl: onCreate
    06-13 10:40:46.438 25215-25215/br.com.gogame D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
    06-13 10:40:46.469 25215-25271/br.com.gogame E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9fb34d0
    06-13 10:40:47.348 25215-26924/br.com.gogame I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:1 and remote module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:2
    06-13 10:40:47.348 25215-26924/br.com.gogame I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.tagmanager, version >= 2
    06-13 10:40:47.428 25215-25215/br.com.gogame D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
    06-13 10:40:47.738 25215-26924/br.com.gogame W/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded)
    06-13 10:40:48.273 25215-25271/br.com.gogame E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9f87b18
    06-13 10:40:48.296 25215-25215/br.com.gogame D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
06-13 10:44:08.361 25215-25221/br.com.gogame I/art: Thread[2,tid=25221,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb9ce2a10,peer=0x12d270a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-13 10:44:08.713 25215-25221/br.com.gogame I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

## EDIT 2

It looks like this issue is related with the use of Firebase and Google Services, however, I need both in my App. The way I'm using them is:

On top gradle file: 
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

On my App gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.gogame"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

    // GOOGLE LIBRARIES
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    // APACHE LIBRARIES
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.0-alpha3'

    // OWN THIRD LIBRARIES
    compile 'br.com.instachat:emoji-library:1.0.6'
    compile 'br.com.edsilfer:kiwi:1.0.8'

    // THIRD PART LIBRARIES
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
    compile 'com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.6@aar'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.6.5@aar'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.15'
    compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:1.5.0'

    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.1'

    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Show your code and Logcat.

Comment: question is off-topic: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* ... so you will get off-topic answer: stop messing with StrictMode and catch networkonmainthread exception ... or check twice if both: obtaining data from internet and parsing are done on non UI thread ... also use lists with recycler patterns (like RecyclerView, ListView, etc) and use it right

Comment: I've edited the question title and added logcat and code snippet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660039/android-app-freezes-after-implementing-google-firebase Try this, Worked for me.

Comment: The way I'm importing google services is like that: I have this in the top gradle file  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0', and in my app module I have apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'. I can't reproduce the answer :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so following @ApplicationDeveloper tip, I've removed `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'` from my project, it wasn't in my main project, it was in a library module. It has solved the question.