# Application Not Responding After Launching ACTION_VIEW Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

After I successfully launching the following intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, SOME_URL));
```

The browser boots up fine and loads the link, but when I try to return to my app the response is sluggish. When the app eventually launches I am met with a black screen, and finally an "Application Not Responding" dialog.

No errors in logcat, no obvious memory issues, nothing to indicate what I did wrong.

The activity that launches the intent is a pretty simple activity, with one fragment:

```
public class LinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_link);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setSupportActionbar(mToolbar);
        setupActionBar();

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content, LinkFragment.newInstance()).commit();
        }
    }

    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if(actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        }
    }

}
```

And the fragment uses a combination of RxJava, RetroFit and Dagger ‡ to load a list of links:

```
public class LinkFragment extends Fragment {

    @Inject RestService mRestService;

    @BindView(R.id.recycler) RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public static LinkFragment newInstance() {
        return new LinkFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_link, container, false);
        Injector.getContextComponent().inject(this);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerDecoration(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new LinkAdapter(new ArrayList<>()));

        mRestService.getLinks()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::onNext, this::onError);

        return view;
    }

    private void onNext(Response<Link> response) [
        LinkAdapter adapter = new LinkAdapter(response.data());
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this::onItemSelected);
        mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, false);
    }

    private void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        Timber.w(throwable, "Failed to obtain links");
    }

    private void onItemSelected(int position, View view, Link link) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, link.getUri());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After finding two similar questions with similar answers ([How to spot app freeze causes when app is returning from pause state?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37791253/5115932), [Android App freezes after implementing Google Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37660039/5115932)) suggesting that adding Google Play Services might be the culprit, I started to investigate.

Both answers suggested that I remove the following dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
```

But my application uses that dependency, as well as the following play services dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2'
```

Previously, I had been using classes from both the core play services library and the wearable play services library in both my mobile module and my wear module. But I noticed that I had removed the need for the wear module in my mobile module, so I removed it from the mobile module (while keeping it in the wear module). Somehow, this fixed the issue.

I have no clue why, so if anyone has any thoughts, please share.