# Goback App, infinite loop (black screen) Android

Tags: android

I discovered an issue on my **Native app**,

I realized that : when I click on my **Home button Android** next, I open any other Android app, after I go back in my app, it seems to be back in an infinite loop (black screen).

However, if I click **Home button Android** and right after, I return immediately on my apps, everything is going well.

Nothing is happening in logs for my app,

I put logs in all methods of lifecycle for my MainActivity and my Fragment, but any method is called...

I desactivated these modules : Firebase and Fabric.io (Crashlytics) but it changes nothing...

From where this bug comes ? I have no idea yet, for information I updated **Android Studio 1.5 to 2.1.2**, the gradle, **buildToolsVerions**...

Maybe the garbage collector is concerned ?

I use....

```
Android Studio 2.1.2

compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
```

**The Gradle Version**

```
gradleVersion = '2.12'
```

Comment: It might be caused by Firebase and the way you're importing Google Services in your project or any of your libraries. TAke a look in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791253/how-to-spot-app-freeze-causes-when-app-is-returning-from-pause-state/37795818#37795818) question

Comment: Thanks for your help I'll look this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue,

It's due to Google Services :

I deleted this line : `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2`

Next, I replaced by this :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
```

(You must only use the libraries you need)

Check that for more informations : 
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project