# Firebase Crash produces ANR during launch

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Recently I got feedback and also I was able to reproduce it easily on my Nexus 5 with cleared app data.
Simply, when adding *compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'* only to project dependencies I get following Exception:

```
09-14 00:47:54.899 3129-3129/com.szyk.myheart E/FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting
                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
                                                               at bol.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:3201)
                                                               at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.api.FirebaseCrashApiImpl.init(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:67)
                                                               at bnu.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:60)
                                                               at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                               at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzd$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                               at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                               at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                               at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The issue is more stranger, because once it will produce ANR and crash, then it works in next launches.

My dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
//not working  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:9.4.0'
```

Comment: Ironic. Adding the crash dependency causes a crash

Comment: We just experienced this issue with devices running version `9.6.80` of google play services. Please check if your device is running the same version.  We had to update all of our apps (loads of users), and remove the crash reporting.

Comment: Exactly, I have GPS 9.6.80 too

Comment: Ugh. It smells a lot like a regression. We'll spend more time on it tomorrow. Thanks for this post!

Comment: *firebaser here* Thanks for the report. We're investigating what may have caused this regression. @bonnyz posted a workaround. I'll post here when there is an update or a proper fix.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm afraid It's a regression in Google Play Services, because it behaves the same way even if you downgrade to 9.2.1 in deps.

Comment: @SzymonKlimaszewski That's indeed the premise we're working under.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue has been introduced with the **Google Play Services 9.6.80** (currently in rollout) and affects all the apps using the *Firebase Crash* reporting (despite of the version bundled in your app).

- Temporary solution: **disable Firebase Crash** by removing the following entry from the build.gradle:

  *compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.x.x'*
- Long term solution: wait that Google releases a fixed version of the GPS before enabling *Firebase Crash* again.

---

### UPDATE 09/16:

Google is rolling out a fixed version of Google Play Services ([9.6.83](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-9-6-83-release/)) which addresses the issue with Firebase Crash.

Comment: I think there is nothing more that we can do about it.

Comment: *firebaser here* Thanks for the report. We're investigating what may have caused this regression. @bonnyz's answer is a valid workaround. I'll post here when there is an update or a proper fix. Update (2016-09-14 12:54 pm pdt): we've identified the cause of the issue and are working on a fix. The workaround remains valid.

Comment: Will you release it as hotfix? If not, then what is an expected release date?

Comment: @SzymonKlimaszewski The problem in 9.6.80 was identified and will be fixed in 9.6.83.  Will keep you updated.

Comment: The status can be tracked here: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Crash%20Reporting%20%28Beta%29/16003

Comment: I removed compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.x.x' from my build.gradle. But still crashing. Google says firebase crash is by default included in apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'. Is there any way to remove firebase crash completely

Comment: That is not true. Make separate question for that

Comment: @SzymonKlimaszewski, Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505604/how-to-disable-default-firebase-crash-reporting

Comment: I don't use firebase-crash in my app, but error still occurred.

Comment: @Alexander.Shtanko see accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505604/how-to-disable-default-firebase-crash-reporting?noredirect=1#comment66354885_39505604

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I encountered the same issue with play services version 9.4.0 and commenting the firebase crash, worked. So the issue might be in 9.4.0 version also?

Comment: When will this be fixed? I know Firebase Crash is Beta, but this is just awful.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue with v11.0.2 again. :(

Answer (score 1):

Disable the Firebase Analytics Crash Reporting, use the below code inside app.gradle file.Hope this will help you

configurations {

```
  all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-crash'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

9.6.83 still gives a different anr crash
Our app when pushed to Play Store Beta and when installed on devices crashes the first time on launch. Subsequently it works , but we cannot push to prod without understanding the issue.

Here is the ANR crash report

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"

Edit : We had to add compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0' explicitly and the launch anr for first time got resolved. But I am not sure that was the fix as we dont use the library at all. Maybe Playstore fixed their bug to all apks?

Comment: That's weird. Does it work when you disable mibification? Maybe they forgot to update Proguard config, or yours has an issue.

Comment: Yes.Disabled proguard as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

We solved the `DynamiteModulesC NPE` and `Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (3.0.0)` by **removing** following line

```
//remove this "feature" if you should use it
FirebaseApp.setAutomaticResourceManagmentEnabled(true)
```

API description:

> If set to true it indicates that Firebase should close database
>   connections automatically when the app is in the background. Disabled
>   by default.

(Might be, that we missed some configurations for correct usage of this feature, but App is working as expected after not enabling the ResourceManagment)