# Latest Google Play Services 9.6.80 cause "FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting"

Tags: android, google-play-services

Notice the latest version when the App is installed fresh, with FirebaseCrash enabled, the App took quite a while (over a minute to start)... and end up with the following crash. Removing firebase crash library from the app help improve the time.

```
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at bol.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:3201)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.api.FirebaseCrashApiImpl.init(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:67)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at bnu.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:60)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzd$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.<init>(Unknown Source)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1789)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1764)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6767)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6362)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6302)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:222)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1861)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
09-14 14:31:08.880 26747 26747 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Play Service library version used is 9.4.0 and Android Support Library version used is 24.2.1.

Nothing on the app specific code is triggered yet when the crash happens.

After some debugging apparently the Device's *Google Play Service* new version caused the issue. If we're on *Google Play Service 9.4.52*, everything works fine. But if the device has upgrade to *Google Play Service 9.6.80*, the app will take very long to load (for the first time) and with a crash as per reported above.

Is there any solution that we could overcome this programmatically or library change?

Comment: Related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480257/firebase-crash-produces-anr-during-launch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/7qS2CoPqxnw. Seems like broad issues that Google should own. The temporally solution is **remove Firebase Crash Library**. The problem should go away

Wait for the fix is done by Google either the **Google Play Service** or **Firebase Crash Library**, as I believe it will get their attention given the wide spread of this issue.

A little more detail here https://medium.com/@elye.project/firebase-crash-report-library-crashes-on-google-play-services-9-6-80-ad630f3b7012#.ocknpw9ob

*Updated* https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Crash%20Reporting%20%28Beta%29/16003