# App hangs with screen blackout on back press from external app

Tags: android, android-intent

I have share option in navigation drawer of my app. On click, its working fine to go respective intent i.e. "share intent". Issue is on pressing back button from whatsapp , my app hangs showing a black screen. Pressing back again does nothing and app has to be killed eventually.I am using coordinator layout. Below are the code snippets:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
sideMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
mSideMenuListAdapter = new SideMenuListAdapter(this, mDrawerLayout);
sideMenu.setAdapter(mSideMenuListAdapter);
```

Adapter Code:

```
 holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  Intent share = new Intent();
  share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  share.setType("text/plain");
  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "XXX");
  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "****"));
  share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share link!"));
  }
  });
```

Tried different options by using different Intent.Flag but nothing seem to be working. Please advise.

Edit:
As asked below is OnCreate method. Have just the starting code as the whole method is quite big initializing lots of stuff.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.home_screen_new);
```

I have have just put the usual methods:

```
@Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Comment: Post your onCreate/onPause/onResume methods in your Activity/Fragment

Comment: check your onResume() code

Comment: @OmarHossam : Done as asked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. There was nothing wrong in my code. It was `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0` that caused problems. Removed this and added specific dependencies. 
Found the solution here : [After Upgrading to Google Play Services 9.0.0, App Hangs in DynamiteModulesC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357974/after-upgrading-to-google-play-services-9-0-0-app-hangs-in-dynamitemodulesc)