# Application blacks out and stops responding when returning back from another app

Tags: android, android-implicit-intent

I am developing this app that contains a webview and also an actionbutton on its Toolbar that would allow the user to send a text message to the a number. Thing is im using an implicit intent and Intent.Action_View to be able to send a text message using default text message tool. The problem is when i press back button either from the toolbar or device button it goes back and does not show anything except a Black screen (fully black screen) and stops responding. Its a strange behaviour. Please let me know what to do about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357974/after-upgrading-to-google-play-services-9-0-0-app-hangs-in-dynamitemodulesc/37379662#37379662

Comment: It resolved my issue, Thanks to you. I had really become fed up with finding solution to it now but thanks. Now it works like a charm. Really Appreciate.