# ANR Reason: executing service com.demo.android/com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerService

Tags: android, firebase, android-anr-dialog, firebase-analytics

I have implemented Firebase Authentication, Realtime Database and Analytics in my app.
If the app is started and remains idle on certain phones, it throws an ANR message.

Logcat shows:

> E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.demo.droid
>   PID: 16376
>   Reason: executing service com.demo.droid/com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerService
>   Load: 8.5 / 8.88 / 8.98
>   CPU usage from 3255ms to -2309ms ago:

Is there any way to catch this error before it is thrown on screen?

Comment: To avoid ANR, place time-consuming operations in a separate thread.

Comment: Maybe [related to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357974/after-upgrading-to-google-play-services-9-0-0-app-hangs-in-dynamitemodulesc)?

Comment: Do you have more details on which phones this happens on, and stack traces for this issue? Have you compiled your app in Android Studio, or via another mechanism (Eclipse, etc)? Is the TagManagerService in the merged AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @EricBurley : phone: Nexus 5, running android M. using Android Studio. The actual problem is that, i haven't even created or implemented the TagManagerService anywhere directly in my app. The app just throws an ANR and logcat shows the message.

Answer (score 0):

ANR cannot be catched. It means that some of your function in UI thread cost too much time

Comment: I received the same ANR all of a sudden, even after the app was closed for about 10 minutes and removed from tray.

Comment: can you give me more details ?