# Google places Api and Google places web service don't show the makers

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-places-api

I used this tutorial ([tutorial link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-with-photos-at-any-location-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/)) in `Android Studio` to do my app(some months ago), after I finish my app it's working and I never touch in the code, but now I want create a new app and when it's was working some days ago, but now it doesn't work (the new app and the old app)and I don't remember touched anything

I checked the keys (the android Key and the browser Key) and it's OK, I activated all Api's `Google Maps` too

I already try delete the keyStore and generate a new key with a new SHA-1 but it doesn't work too

I already try update the Google play service 8.1.0 to Google play service 9.0.1(or 2) and it does't worked too.
(Google play service 8.1.0 is the version I'm using and the version which it's worked in the last time some days ago)

I tried a lot things but anyone worked, my app just is taking my location now

the LogCat (new app):

```
06-29 17:18:24.974 9778-9788/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/art: Debugger is no longer active
06-29 17:36:15.197 2491-3353/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
06-29 17:36:15.205 2491-3353/com.fastcoding.testemapa E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
06-29 17:36:15.206 2491-3353/com.fastcoding.testemapa E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
06-29 17:36:15.461 2491-2491/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/zzy: Making Creator dynamically
06-29 17:36:15.472 2491-2491/com.fastcoding.testemapa W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
06-29 17:36:15.472 2491-2491/com.fastcoding.testemapa W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
06-29 17:36:15.563 2491-2504/com.fastcoding.testemapa W/art: Suspending all threads took: 24.272ms
06-29 17:36:15.593 2491-2509/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17707(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 29(484KB) LOS objects, 17% free, 9MB/12MB, paused 10.088ms total 93.136ms
06-29 17:36:15.610 2491-2491/com.fastcoding.testemapa D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Reading stored module config
06-29 17:36:15.692 2491-2491/com.fastcoding.testemapa D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is armeabi-v7a
06-29 17:36:15.696 2491-2491/com.fastcoding.testemapa D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
06-29 17:36:15.944 2491-2491/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 8115000
06-29 17:36:15.957 2491-2491/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 9256236
06-29 17:36:16.634 2491-3419/com.fastcoding.testemapa D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-29 17:36:16.647 2491-2491/com.fastcoding.testemapa D/Atlas: Validating map...
06-29 17:36:16.704 2491-3423/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/b: Sending API token request.
06-29 17:36:16.812 2491-3419/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
Build Date: 02/11/15 Wed
Local Branch: 
Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.10
Local Patches: NONE
Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.
02.042.016 + 62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 +
cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 + 23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 
33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 + b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
06-29 17:36:16.817 2491-3419/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-29 17:36:16.885 2491-3419/com.fastcoding.testemapa D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
06-29 17:36:18.526 2491-3408/com.fastcoding.testemapa W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
06-29 17:36:18.539 2491-3408/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1
06-29 17:36:18.539 2491-3408/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 1
06-29 17:36:18.559 2491-3408/com.fastcoding.testemapa D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is armeabi-v7a
06-29 17:36:18.560 2491-3408/com.fastcoding.testemapa D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
06-29 17:36:18.569 2491-3408/com.fastcoding.testemapa D/GoogleCertificates: com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates module is loaded
06-29 17:36:18.786 2491-3408/com.fastcoding.testemapa D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 163 Google release certificates
06-29 17:36:18.795 2491-3408/com.fastcoding.testemapa D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 318 Google certificates
06-29 17:36:18.991 2491-3423/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/b: Received API Token: AH0uPGEnEpxLuGLFBvrjC3jF4bdpKGY667r-rBI8ITB6jrjPy03SrXHJx7kQxYVZyRj0Wu65Po4HxkuYnVaaJ4hqW37WhejH3jDPpSNX8K1LyLeOAuxCraU37jpvRZuUjslkW5FWpVfZfHXaQqoTyBJzZK-OwiGyStIjQOGuj5_udSZrCYdfB9aE9wlhhOcNYYcxP4mncLnk / Expires in: 432000000ms
06-29 17:36:18.991 2491-3423/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/c: Scheduling next attempt in 431700 seconds.
06-29 17:36:18.997 2491-3423/com.fastcoding.testemapa I/d: Saved auth token
```

Manifest(new app):

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.fastcoding.testemapa.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.fastcoding.testemapa.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

`build.gradle` (Module:app) (new app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fastcoding.testemapa"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'

}
```

This is my app code on GitHub:
old app : [GitHub's link to old app](https://github.com/italojs/AppBebado_TCC/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/fastcoding/appbebado/Mapa) this was working, but now isn't
new app : [GitHub's link to new app](https://github.com/italojs/Cola/tree/master/Java/Android/testeMapa(Google%20Place%20API)/app/src/main/java/com/fastcoding/testemapa)

Please, someone have some solution? Thank You very much

Comment: Have you tried using Google play service 9.2? Or tried adding the following [keep option](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions) to your ProGuard configuration file: `-keep public @com.google.android.gms.common.util.DynamiteApi class * { *; }` for [Known Issues with version 9.0.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_2016_-_v90).

Comment: yes, I tried use Google play service 9.2 too

Comment: I would suggest you use `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4`. Also here's a topic you might want to read [Google Play Services 9.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37379662/5995040). If you want to use Play Services 9.0.0, "you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app." Hope this helps

Comment: it's working now, but it just work if I open the app with the location disabled and active it when the app is running, if I open the app with the location actived, it doesn't work